# Field-level editibility based on User field values

Tags: field-level-security

I only want users to be able to edit certain fields if they named in certain User lookup fields within the record. So the editability would be on a record-by-record basis.

In other words, if the current user is named in the Manager__c field the user should be able to edit FieldA__c.

What is the best approach to this ? Is it possible without VisualForce ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd imagine some sort of trigger that automatically creates record shares for the desired users would work. You'd want to make sure those users' profiles don't have access to anything you don't want them to modify.

Alternatively, if you have open security you could try a validation rule to be something like:

```
AND(
 NOT($User.Id = Custom_Object__c.Manager__c),
 ISCHANGED(FieldA__c)
)
```

Would stop users from changing the field unless they are the user referenced in the specific field.

### Update

You can validate your record in the trigger using any logic you see fit to control who has access or when that field can be edited. The below is similar to the above validation rule.

```
if (Trigger.IsBefore && Trigger.IsUpdate) {
    for (record r : trigger.new) {
        if (trigger.oldMap.get(r.Id).field__c != r.field && (
            UserInfo.getUserId() != Manager_Field__c)) {
            record.addError('You must be the manager to update this record');
        }
    }
}
```

You can expand this to further to try to achieve what you need.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was going to say.

Comment: That is a really great (and simple) solution. However, what if I want to allow the users to edit the field through the approval process ? I think the validation would cause an error .. ? To let you know, it's a type of Status__c field in a project management app which I only want set through the approval process - unless a manager decides to put the project on hold - and they could just choose "On Hold".

Comment: Theoretically you could add more users or a profile into the validation rule to open it up to the approvers as well as the manager but if you need people who are not approvers or managers to edit it you'd still run into the error. I've updated my answer with a third option that might help you in your situation as it provides a bit more flexibility.

Comment: I think I'm going to just go with the solution of moving the necessary management to new Profiles, and go w/ the different Page Layouts. It's way too much effort otherwise. And inevitably more fields will be needed with with this type of situation in the object. That means more in the trigger or more validation rules etc.  Thank you gNerb & sfdfox.